# how do I correctly wrap a function with dynamic number of args up?

Tags: c, dynamic, arguments, wrapper, vxworks

I want to wrap a function that looks like: `void dbgLog (tDbgLog *dbg, const char *mod, const char *func, const char *format,...)` and makes use of `vsnprintf()` to make it accessible by calling another function, I've tried the following but that doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
void pMonDbgLog(const char *mod, const char *func, char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,fmt);
    dbgLog(g_pdbg,mod,func,fmt,args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

and I again make this accessible through the following macro:`#define gDbgLog(fmt,...)      pMonDbgLog(MODULE_NAME,__FUNCTION__,fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)` but turns out that my arguments get messed up. Why is this, I'm wondering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no portable way to pass the arguments of a vararg function to another vararg function.  You can implement `dbgLog` by calling a function `vdbgLog` defined as:

```
void vdbgLog(tDbgLog *dbg, const char *mod, const char *func,
             const char *format, va_list ap) {
    /* your implementation goes here */
}

void dbgLog(tDbgLog *dbg, const char *mod, const char *func, const char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vdbgLog(dbg, mod, func, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

And you can call this function `vdbgLog` directly from `pMonDbgLog` as well:

```
void pMonDbgLog(const char *mod, const char *func, char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vdbgLog(g_pdbg, mod, func, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The function dbgLog must take an argument of type va_list and not variable arguments via the ellipsis:

```
void dbgLog(tDbgLog*dbg, const char *mod, const char *func, const char *format, va_list list)
                                                                                ^^^^^^^
```

The argument list, in the function dbgLog, is then passed to function vsnprintf.